# Azure Devops Extension- PublishHTMLReport in Azure pipelines not producing HTML tab in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am having issue with this extension (Azure Devops Extension- PublishHTMLReport) somehow HTML tab is not appearing in the Azure Devops.
The below config of this plugin:
***htmltype: Jmeter
JmeterReportsPath: D:\a\r1\a\HTMLReports***

Prior to the above task, I am using CMD task as below:
***echo 'JMeter'
jmeter -n -t _JmeterTest\JmeterWebApp.jmx -l _JmeterTest\Summary.jtl -e -o HTMLReports***

In the log, it is generating HTML content but not publishing HTML report using Publish HTML Report extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the path of the report is consistent.

In this command line,

```
jmeter -n -t _JmeterTest\JmeterWebApp.jmx -l _JmeterTest\Summary.jtl -e -o HTMLReports
```

The output folder should be generated in the directory '**`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`**', in your case it should be "**`D:\a\r1\s\`**".

However, on the **`publishhtmlreport`** task, I noticed that path you set is "**`D:\a\r1\a\HTMLReports`**", it equals to "**`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\HTMLReports`**".

So, please try to change the **`JmeterReportsPath`** to "**`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HTMLReports`**" on the **`publishhtmlreport`** task to see if it work.

You also can reference to the sample [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LakshayKaushik.PublishHTMLReports).

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

The extension [**PublishHTMLReports**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LakshayKaushik.PublishHTMLReports) has some issues are causing the HTML report can't be publish to the Azure pipelines.

Turning to using the extension [**Html Viewer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubRumpca.azure-pipelines-html-report&ssr=false#overview) can solve the problem. It can work fine as expected.

Comment: Have you tried yourself in the release pipeline, I have already incorporated this plugin guidelines, I am getting the error is: Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=firstscriptname;name=content;]$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\HTMLReports/content/js/dashboard-commons.js' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
[error]Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or not exist on disk'). it finds the file .js but it gets failed

Comment: in addition to my above comment, I did echo on this directory. Directory of D:\a\r1\a\HTMLReports
    <DIR>          .
   <DIR>          ..
    <DIR>          content
           9,670 index.html
   <DIR>          sbadmin2-1.0.7
             2,998 statistics.json
               2 File(s)         12,668 bytes
                4 Dir(s)  14,701,731,840 bytes free

Comment: Hi @Anil, Alright. Your issue is more likely occurs on the extension itself. Maybe you can report this issue to the [**Q & A**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LakshayKaushik.PublishHTMLReports&ssr=false#qna) tab of this extension. Or report on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lakshaykaushik/PublishHTMLReport/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails) of it.

Comment: Thanks, There are some issues with this extension. Alernatively, I am trying to use HTML Viewer extension. below are the configs of reportDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/HTMLReports/index.html'. and pipeline is successful but now able to see HTML report anywhere in the release pipeine. as you can see the output of HTML viewer task is : 2021-03-29T04:03:53.3782081Z 
Task         : Publish Html Report
Description  : Publish Html Report
Version      : 1.0.8
Help         : Replace with markdown to show in help
D:\a\r1\a\HTMLReports\index.html
Finishing: Publish Html Report

Comment: Hi @Anil, thanks for your reply. So, after you turn to use the [Html Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubRumpca.azure-pipelines-html-report&ssr=false#overview) extension in your pipeline can solve the problem. Right? I have updated my answer with a summary of your solution. Please check it. Maybe you can mark it as the solution of this topic, this may also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, What I mean, I tried to use HTML Viewer but that did not work either in release pipeline.

Comment: Alright, maybe you need to contact the develop team of the extension for more support.

Comment: It will be waste of time again as I did with same PublishHTMLReport, it looks like nothing has developed for HTML Report in release pipeline